# Are iPhones and iPads TAA compliant?

Tags: iphone, ipad

The Trade Agreement Act (TAA) of 1979 was designed to improve trade agreements, foster an open world trade system, expand US commerce opportunities, and improve international trade rules.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_Agreements_Act_of_1979

Are iPhones and iPads TAA compliant?

Comment: What does TAA compliant mean - and what happens if not

Comment: In short, a product is said to be TAA compliant if is manufactured or substantially transformed in a designated country. US government contracts are supposed to purchase TAA compliant products.  Read the WP page or Google for more.